# How to write matrix A as the sum of basic solutions

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra

Let

[A = [[1,−4,−2,−4],[4,−16,-8,-16]]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE3t8.jpg)

Describe all solutions of the homogeneous system that has A as its coefficient matrix, as a sum of basic solutions.

[x= x2[ ] + x3[ ] + x4[ ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z7Ov.jpg)

Comment: You wrote down what the task demands from you. But what is *your* question? And why are you posting a linear algebra question that is to be manually solved in a programming forum?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming. It is more of a math question, but to be accepted on http://math.stackexchange.com/ it would need a clearer indication of how far you got solving this, where you got stuck, what techniques you have at your disposal and so on. Read the help pages before posting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to reduce it to RREF (Row-Reduced Echelon Form),
which will give you

A = [1 -4 -2 -4]
    [0  0  0  0]

We now know x1 = 4x2 + 2x3 + 4x4 and x2, x3 and x4 are free variables

thus, x1 = x2[4 1 0  0] + x3[2 0 1 0] + x4[4 0 0 1]

Programming == Maths